# display number of lines (pictures in slideshow) in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, slideshow, image

I modified the following code of a slideshow to work with lightbox and it works great for me.

The only thing that's missing is something to show how many pictures there will be.

A simple number displayed next to the slideshow like "15" would be nice, two numbers like "7 of 15" would be cool, the absolute burner would be thumbnails highlighted the showing picture.

Ok, here's the whole code. I left the credits in.
I would like to know how many "ulitmateshow[x]-images" there are.

Since I have no glue about Javascript, help would be much appreciated.

---

Edit: Someone knows how to display the number of the showing picture? Then we would be at stage "cool"

```
// Flexible Image Slideshow- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com)
// For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/
// This notice must stay intact for use

var ultimateshow=new Array()

//ultimateshow[x]=["path to image", "OPTIONAL link for image", "OPTIONAL link target"]

ultimateshow[0]=['images/image_1_x.jpg', 'images/image_1_b.jpg', '', 'lightbox[image]', 'title blabla']
ultimateshow[1]=['images/image_2_x.jpg', 'images/image_2_b.jpg', '', 'lightbox[image]', 'title blabla']
ultimateshow[2]=['images/image_3_x.jpg', 'images/image_3_b.jpg', '', 'lightbox[image]', 'title blabla']
ultimateshow[3]=['images/image_4_x.jpg', 'images/image_4_b.jpg', '', 'lightbox[image]', 'title blabla']
ultimateshow[4]=['images/image_5_x.jpg', 'images/image_5_b.jpg', '', 'lightbox[image]', 'title blabla']

//configure the below 3 variables to set the dimension/background color of the slideshow

var slidewidth="500px" //set to width of LARGEST image in your slideshow
var slideheight="334px" //set to height of LARGEST iamge in your slideshow
var slidecycles="continous" //number of cycles before slideshow stops (ie: "2" or "continous")
var randomorder="yes" //randomize the order in which images are displayed? "yes" or "no"
var preloadimages="yes" //preload images? "yes" or "no"
var slidebgcolor='#c0c0c0'

//configure the below variable to determine the delay between image rotations (in miliseconds)
var slidedelay=3000

////Do not edit pass this line////////////////

var ie=document.all
var dom=document.getElementById
var curcycle=0

if (preloadimages=="yes"){
for (i=0;i<ultimateshow.length;i++){
var cacheimage=new Image()
cacheimage.src=ultimateshow[i][0]
}
}

var currentslide=0

function randomize(targetarray){
ultimateshowCopy=new Array()
var the_one
var z=0
while (z<targetarray.length){
the_one=Math.floor(Math.random()*targetarray.length)
if (targetarray[the_one]!="_selected!"){
ultimateshowCopy[z]=targetarray[the_one]
targetarray[the_one]="_selected!"
z++
}
}
}

if (randomorder=="yes")
randomize(ultimateshow)
else
ultimateshowCopy=ultimateshow

function rotateimages(){
curcycle=(currentslide==0)? curcycle+1 : curcycle
ultcontainer='<center>'
if (ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][1]!="")
ultcontainer+='<a href="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][1]+'" target="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][2]+'" rel="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][3]+'" title="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][4]+'">'
ultcontainer+='<img src="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][0]+'" border="0">'
if (ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][1]!="")
ultcontainer+='</a>'
ultcontainer+='</center>'
if (ie||dom)
crossrotateobj.innerHTML=ultcontainer
if (currentslide==ultimateshow.length-1) currentslide=0
else currentslide++
if (curcycle==parseInt(slidecycles) && currentslide==0)
return
setTimeout("rotateimages()",slidedelay)
}

if (ie||dom)
document.write('<div id="slidedom" style="width:'+slidewidth+';height:'+slideheight+'; background-color:'+slidebgcolor+'"></div>')

function start_slider(){
crossrotateobj=dom? document.getElementById("slidedom") : document.all.slidedom
rotateimages()
}

if (ie||dom)
window.onload=start_slider
```

Comment: Are you wanting just to know how many pictures there are??

Comment: actually yes - I know, must be simple... :(

Comment: `ultimateshow.length` will tell you how many images there are.

Comment: here as well ;-) ...sounds good for me. but where do I ad this lines to get an output? thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `length` property of the array object.

```
var imageCount = ultimateshow.length;
console.log(imageCount) //logs image count
```

Comment: ...sounds good for me. but where do I ad this lines to get an output? thanx

Comment: You put `imageCount` wherever you would want the total to be.  The example above just logs the value in the console of the browser.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but do I put it in the .js or the .html file? Do I have to call it in a special way?

Comment: No, you can just put it in the .js file.  JavaScript will output the variable value, in this case the number of the images.

Comment: ...hmm, at any place? I did that. Didn't show me anything. Solved it for now with a <script>document.write(imageCount)</script>
Any chance to find out the number of the displayed picture as well?

Comment: ok - figured it out to show it from .js file. Thanx a lot for that. Learned something today. :-)

Comment: Sweet!  If this is the answer you were looking for, mark it as the correct answer.